# Angular: detect parent component data changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I have a parent component which calls a dataservice.
In this component I define my columns:

```
tableInterventionsColumns: TableColumn<Interventions>[] = [

    {
      label: 'Date',
      property: 'dateIntervention',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      label: 'Type',
      property: 'TypeIntervention',
      type: 'text',
      cssClasses: ['font-medium']
    },
    {
      label: 'Comments',
      property: 'RemarqueIntervention',
      type: 'text',
      cssClasses: ['text-secondary']
    }
    ,
    {
      label: 'Technician',
      property: 'InstallateurIntervention',
      type: 'text',
      cssClasses: ['text-secondary']
    }
    ,
    {
      label: 'Device',
      property: 'typeBoitierIntervention',
      type: 'text',
      cssClasses: ['text-secondary']
    }
  ];
```

I also get the data from the dataservice that I put in an array:

```
tableInterventionsData: Interventions[];

.........

this.TankDetailsService.getInterventions(this.idCit).subscribe((Interventions: Interventions[]) => {
      
      this.tableInterventionsData = Interventions;

    });
```

I can see the 2 array in the console.

I call my child component in my template passing the data

```
<vex-widget-table-interventions [columns]="tableInterventionsColumns"
                    [data]="tableInterventionsData"
                    class="w-full overflow-auto shadow" gdColumn="3 / -1"
                    gdColumn.lt-md="1 / -1"
                    gdColumn.lt-sm="1"></vex-widget-table-interventions>
```

I have a child component which must create a datatable by retrieving the 2 arrays.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import icMoreHoriz from '@iconify/icons-ic/twotone-more-horiz';
import icCloudDownload from '@iconify/icons-ic/twotone-cloud-download';
import { TableColumn } from '../../../interfaces/table-column.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'vex-widget-table-interventions',
  templateUrl: './widget-table-interventions.component.html'
})
export class WidgetTableInterventionsComponent<T> implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() data: T[];
  @Input() columns: TableColumn<T>[];
  @Input() pageSize = 6;

  visibleColumns: Array<keyof T | string>;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<T>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  icMoreHoriz = icMoreHoriz;
  icCloudDownload = icCloudDownload;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log(this.columns);
    
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.columns) {
      this.visibleColumns = this.columns.map(column => column.property);
    }

    if (changes.data) {
      this.dataSource.data = this.data;
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that it retrieves the columns well but no data.

Do you have an idea to help a beginner on Angular?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended to use ngOnChanges for that purpose. As you can read [here](https://www.stackchief.com/blog/ngOnChanges%20Example%20%7C%20Angular), its purpose is to use the current and previous values.
So in your code:

```
this.dataSource.data = this.data.currentValue
```

I suggest to pass instead of the array data an Observable of it.

Starting from the parent component:

```
this.tableInterventionsData = this.TankDetailsService.getInterventions(this.idCit)
```

Then in the child component WidgetTableInterventionsComponent:

```
@Input() data: Observable<T[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
With your advice everything is working now!
Thanks thanks thanks!